# How can i call a class without including the php-file?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm working on a new project in PHP and try to use MVC for this (use it the first time in PHP). I created an autoloader-class, which includes my controllers if I call them (got the code from the web somewhere).

Now, I've got another problem: I can call my controllers, but I can't call my views and models from my controller.

My autoload.php looks like this:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'controller/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

My workspace looks like this:

[image]

What can I do to autoload my Model and View classes without including them?

Comment: Do the same autoloading but with 'view/' and 'model/'? Am I understanding your problem correctly?

Comment: If i define 3 diffrent includings it tries to include controller, model and view if I call new PageController for example and this create some errors ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **namespaces** and then use the **psr-0** or **psr-4** autoload standard.

Google will be your friend :-)

Comment: No problem. This will help too: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=php+namespace